# mysql - how to UPDATE after LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, select

I have create a SELECT from two tables:

```
SELECT  p.products_id, p.gender, f.feature_set_id, f.products_id
FROM products_item_codes AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN feature_set_to_products AS f ON p.products_id = f.products_id

products_id gender feature_set_id products_íd
       1235 Damen               7        1235
       1236 Damen               7        1236
       1237                  NULL        NULL
       1238 Herren           NULL        NULL
       1239 Herren           NULL        NULL
       1240 Damen               7        1240
```

How can I UPDATE the feature_set_id and products_id?

- gender='Herren' , feature_set_id='6'
- gender='Damen' , feature_set_id='7'

The NULL-datasets doesnt exist, I will create them.

Comment: you can not at the same time make a last days to two fields with different values to the same with condiction

Comment: Would it be an update or an insert?

Comment: You want a select insert ? and what do you need for product_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an [insert ... select ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement to fill up the `feature_set_to_products` table. A case statement can take care of the appropriate feature_set_id to be inserted based on gender.

```
insert into feature_set_to_products (feature_set_id, products_id)
select case when p.gender='Damen' then 7 when p.gender='Herren' then 6 else null end, p.products_id
from products_item_codes p
left join feature_set_to_products AS f ON p.products_id = f.products_id
where p.gender in ('Damen', 'Herren') and f.products_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Shadow commented, you have to `INSERT`, because the rows do not exist.

However, given you want to set values in 2 tables at once because `gender` is from `products_item_codes`, while `feature_set_id` is from `feature_set_to_products`, you'll have to use **at least** 2 insert queries.
You should either use a transaction, or do the insert at the application level (ie. PHP, Perl, or whatever language you use)

Comment: I will only set the new values in the `feature_set_to_products` table.